How to resolve the responsiveness issue with my website, it appears differently on laptops
I have a tab on my website with 3 images. On desktop and mobile, they look good, but on a laptop, the images are crooked. How do I resolve this responsiveness issue? (The website was made in Shopify, and I couldn't find any solution within Shopify.)
on a laptop
on a desktop (the right one)
I tried to fix it through Shopify's theme settings, but I couldn't manage it. It might be a code issue, but I don't understand anything about programming.
